# Python combine name in list output name and count

Tags: python, list, format

I have a text file with names on them:

```
Baltimore Colts
Dallas Cowboys
Dallas Cowboys
Dallas Cowboys
Denver Broncos
Green Bay Packers
Dallas Cowboys
Indianapolis Colts
Indianapolis Colts
```

i made a list in python with all the names in it:

```
[Baltimore Colts, Dallas Cowboys, Dallas Cowboys, Dallas Cowboys, Denver Broncos, Dallas Cowboys, Indianapolis Colts, Indianapolis Colts]
```

How can i turn this list to come out like this:

```
Baltimore Colts      1
Dallas Cowboys       4
Denver Broncos       1
Green Bay Packers    1          <--------- with the numbers centered
Indianapolis Colts   2
```

it reads name then counts how many times in list then goes to another name.

Comment: By the way, the Baltimore Ravens are going to be very upset when they find out they've been renamed the Colts :P

Answer (score 3):

```
l = ['Baltimore Colts', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Denver Broncos', 'Dallas Cowboys', 'Indianapolis Colts', 'Indianapolis Colts']
```

Use `collections.Counter` to count the number of occurrences of each team

```
counts = Counter(l)

>>> counts
Counter({'Dallas Cowboys': 4, 'Indianapolis Colts': 2, 'Baltimore Colts': 1, 'Denver Broncos': 1})
```

Then use `format` to left and right justify the columns.

```
for team in counts:
    print('{:<20} {:>2}'.format(team, counts[team]))
```

Output

```
Baltimore Colts       1
Denver Broncos        1
Indianapolis Colts    2
Dallas Cowboys        4
```

Comment: You should use `collections.Counter` instead of a list comprehension.  Aside from being more elegant, it avoids all those calls to `list.count`, each one of which has `O(n)` complexity.  So, your current solution is `O(n**2)`, which isn't very efficient.  Otherwise, nice work. +1

Comment: @iCodez Fair enough, I switched that part of the solution out to use Counter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

teams = ['Baltimore Colts',
         'Dallas Cowboys',
         'Dallas Cowboys',
         'Dallas Cowboys',
         'Denver Broncos',
         'Dallas Cowboys',
         'Indianapolis Colts',
         'Indianapolis Colts']
c = Counter(teams)
# Counter({'Dallas Cowboys': 4, 'Indianapolis Colts': 2, 'Denver Broncos': 1, 'Baltimore Colts': 1})
print c['Dallas Cowboys']
# Prints 4
```

Reading a list from a file is another matter:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    teams = f.readlines()
```

Comment: yes i tried that but how do i format that into the example i gave with numbers centered?

Comment: The other answer to your question has the correct formatting, so I won't repeat it here. I'll leave my answer up though because I believe `Counter`, a built-in python object, does exactly what you need to do.